# sakis3g installation

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have got`sakis3g.tar.gz` file on my pc but as soon as I try to make this file executable using the command `sudo chmod +x sakis3g` it shows:

> `NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY`

I have been wanting to use 3g dongle on my pc running UBUNTU 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

A `.tar.gz` file is an archive, not a program - you can't make it executable.

You have missed a step in the instructions on the [Sakis 3G website](http://www.sakis3g.com/). Before `chmod`, you need to do

```
 tar -xzvf sakis3g.tar.gz
```

**Edit**: 
HOWEVER... please read the comments below from LiveWireBT and consider obtaining this script from an alternative source.

Comment: Please take a look at the footer of the website, while the site asks for donations it's not owned by the author of the program. Apparently this site is owned by the company incapsula.com and if you connect to the site via HTTPS you can see that they have 150 other sites in the certificate. This looks like a domain grabbing scam, please stop promoting this site. According to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem#sakis3g) the original script is hosted on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-n4n0/files/).

Comment: I'm also wondering why `wget`, `tar` and `chmod` are run with sudo. There is more, this isn't just a simple script it also contains compressed content and this version is different from the one you find on Sourceforge, though they seem to have the same version number.

Comment: @LiveWireBT All very good points - I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you download the `tar.gz` file from [Sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.com/downloads/sakis3g.tar.gz) and run:

> `sudo tar -xzvf sakis3g.tar.gz`

you are going to get a directory called `files` with 2 more directories inside it (at least as on June 14,2015, may have been working well before/after today). So the actual location of script is:

> `files/fgsvmqk3jv8ajq2673u21hkbh4/targz/sakis3g`

I think this is because of the way in which the file is `tar.gz`pped by the uploader.

So run:

> `sudo chmod +x files/fgsvmqk3jv8ajq2673u21hkbh4/targz/sakis3g`

from the same place you ran the `tar` command above.

Comment: IF this answered your question you can mark it as the answer.